# Is there a best-practise method to swap primary key values using SQL Lite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

As a bit of background, I'm working with a SQL Lite database that is being consumed by a closed-source UI that doesn't order the results by the handy timestamp column (gee, thanks Nokia!) - it just uses the default ordering, which corresponds to the primary key, which is a vanilla auto-incrementing 'id' column.

I easily have a map of the current and desired id values, but applying the mapping is my current problem. It seems I cannot swap the values as an update processes rows one at a time, which would temporarily result in a duplicate value. I've tried using an update statement with case clauses using a temporary out-of-sequence value, but as each row is only processed once this obviously doesn't work. Thus I've reached the point of needing 3 update statements to swap a pair of values, which is far from ideal as I want this to scale well.

Compounded to this, there are a number of triggers set up which makes adding/deleting rows into a new table a complex problem unless I can disable those for the duration of any additions/deletions resulting from table duplication & deletion, which is why I haven't pursued that avenue yet.

I'm thinking my next line of enquiry will be a new column with the new ids then finding a way to move the primary index to it before removing the old column, but I'm throwing this out there in case anyone can offer up a better solution that will save me some time :)

Comment: Ah, ok. SQL Lite only supports a very limited subset of ALTER TABLE, so I won't be changing the primary key then.

...as an addendum, my intention is to add in new records to the table from an external source. In the most likely use-case, the majority of the old records won't need to be altered, just a largish chuck or so at the end will need to be interleaved with the end of the current records.

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand your goal.  I understand that your UI sorts by the INT PK and I think you'd prefer it to sort using timestamp. But what exactly is the problem caused by its sorting on the autoincrementing id? That I do not understand yet.

Comment: The problem is that the UI is displaying events in chronological order. This is fine as in normal usage, they will only be inserted in the order they occurred. The problem comes from the fact I'm writing a syncing tool to import events. New records may have occurred before existing events, so in order for them to be displayed correctly, the resulting record IDs will need to be adjusted. Unnecessary if the UI had an order by clause, but I can understand why they left it out. Sadly, I can't add it, so I have to adjust the IDs to get the same effect.

Comment: Are we talking Qt? Can you add an ORDER BY to the sql statement? Or perhaps you're using one of the item views and its default model (e.g., QTableWidget)?